# Manual deployment of  Tomcat app by copying to webapps

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I'm trying to deploy a Tomcat application by copying it to the `webapps` directory. My `webapps` directory looks like:

```
webapps/test
           |_ index.jsp
           |_ WEB-INF
                    |_ lib
                         |_ test.jar
```

The contents of `index.jsp` are:

```
<html>
    Test App<br>
    <%= com.stevekuo.Test.test() %>
</htm>
```

`test.jar` has the `Test` class with the static `test()` method that just returns a string.

When I access my app via `http://tomcatserver:8080/test/`, all I get is:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
com.stevekuo.Test cannot be resolved to a type
1: <html>
2:     Test<br>
3:     <%= com.stevekuo.Test.test() %>
4: </html>
```

I've also tried packaging the above directory structure into a WAR file and copying to `webapps`, but it still gives the same error.

I'm running standard out-of-the-box Tomcat 6 on Ubuntu 10.04. Tomcat came installed by Ubuntu. All files have `-rw-r--r--` permissions, and directories are `drwxr-xr-x`. Why can't Tomcat resolve the `Test` class located in `WEB-INF/lib/test.jar`?

Comment: Are you sure your compiled class is in your jar file?  Have you tried deploying the webapp via the Tomcat manager page?

Comment: Yes I'm sure the JAR is correct. It also contains a main method that I can invoke via `java com.stevekuo.Test -jar test.jar`

Comment: What about deploying using the Tomcat manager page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I added an empty `web.xml` and it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app 
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" 
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
</web-app>
```

Comment: If you'd taken my advice and used the Tomcat manager page to deploy it you would have had this solved 39 minutes ago :)

Comment: Does the Tomcat Manager automatically create a `web.xml`?

Comment: I don't know, but I know how you can find out :)

Answer (score 0):

have you imported `com.stevekuo.Test` you need to say `<%@ page import="com.stevekuo.Test"%>`

this is most definitely the fault.

Comment: You don't need to import it if you use the fully qualified name, which he does.

Comment: That won't make a difference. My reference to `Test` is fully qualified (ie, `com.stevekuo.Test`)